# Can/should one share the same user directory for different domain accounts

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

For work I frequently need to log into two different accounts on different domains, one at a time.  I have different user names in each.

It would be convenient to share the same local user directory for these two accounts.
Is this possible?  If so, how?

Are there gotchas that are likely to make me regret doing this?

Are there half-measures that would be wiser/easier than sharing the entire user directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. Set the `profilepath` property of the correct sid under `\\hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\profilelist\<sid>`.

Any gotchas? You'd probably be giving access to the domain administrators of domain 1 to your files used for business on domain 2. Also, if you're using a network folder to store your user directory in, you of course should make sure you have network access to that folder *before* logging in, how you accomplish that is a separate question.

Instead of sharing the entire user folder, I would probably just create a symlink to the folder and store the actual folder somewhere else (network drive perhaps, but it doesn't matter), that way I have a consistent (desktop, for example) across both accounts, etc.